# Getting Index Number from pandastable

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, tkinter

I am trying to display pandas dataframe in tkinter window and I got to know about pandastable Library. As of now I am able to display my dataframe in the pandastable using the below code but I am stuck in an issue. 
Now if I select/click on some index in the pandastable the corresponding row gets highlighted in the table. 
Issue is I wanted to **get the selected Index number** from the pandastable when I click on a particular index in the pandastable.

As of now I tried **get_row_clicked(event)** & **getSelectedRow()** but its giving me only row number clicked/selected.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from pandastable import Table, TableModel
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(path to CSV file)

app = Tk()
app.geometry('600x400+200+100')
app.title('Table app')
f = tk.Frame(app)
f.pack(fill=BOTH,expand=1)

table = pt = Table(f, dataframe=df,
                        showtoolbar=True, showstatusbar=True)

pt.show()

def handle_left_click(event):   
    rowclicked = pt.get_row_clicked(event)
    print("RowClicked", rowclicked)
    rowsel = pt.getSelectedRow()
    print("RowSelected", rowsel) 

table.bind("<Button-1>",handle_left_click)

app.mainloop()
```

I expect to get index value as 2 if I click on the second index of the pandastable and so on.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Got the solution... There is something called table.rowheader.bind event in the documentation which gives us the required index number when it is selected. I have used the following code to get the solution:

```
from pandastable import Table, TableModel
import tkinter as tk
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_file("Read your CSV file")

app = tk.Toplevel()

app.title('Table app')
f = tk.Frame(app)
f.pack(fill=BOTH,expand=1)

table = pt = Table(f, dataframe=df, showtoolbar=True, showstatusbar=True)

pt.show()

def handle_left_click(event):
    """Handle left click"""
    rowclicked_single = table.get_row_clicked(event)
    print(rowclicked_single)
    table.setSelectedRow(rowclicked_single)
    table.redraw()

pt.rowheader.bind('<Button-1>',handle_left_click)

app.mainloop()
```

Comment: I am trying to do somthing similar to what you did. Can you please post the code for the solution? (I am not able to find anything about rowheader.bind in the source code https://pandastable.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/pandastable/core.html#Table.getCellCoords). Much appreciated.